# Why method in Runnable works only one time?

Tags: android, runnable

As you can see method *refreshProgressBars()* works only one time, although Toast created without interruption. **How it possible?!**

```
 bREnemyRegeneration = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                refreshProgressBars(); //method works only 1 time
                Toast.makeText( //works always
                      BattleActivity.this, 
                      "THIS TOAST WILL BE SHOWN", 
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bHandlerTimers.postDelayed(bREnemyRegeneration, 3000); //start new iteration of this Runnable
            }
        };
```

Just in case method *refreshProgressBars()*:

```
public void refreshProgressBars(){
    checkDeath();
    if (bHealthsBar.getLayoutParams().width < 30) bHealthsBar.getLayoutParams().width = 0;
    else bHealthsBar.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (PB_EN_HP_WIDTH * bEnemy.getHealth(false) / bEnemy.getHealth(true));
}
```

Runnable calls as follows:

```
bHandlerTimers = new Handler();
bHandlerTimers.post(bREnemyRegeneration);
```

Comment: As it turned out method _refreshProgressBar()_ too works always, but **healths bar width changes only one time**, how make it change always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit method *refreshProgressBar()* as follows:
Instead 
`bHealthsBar.getLayoutParams().width = bWidth` 
I used 
`bHealthsBar.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(bWidth, bHealthsBar.getLayoutParams().height));`

And... all works! Question is closed.

Comment: mark the answer as solved when the system let you do it.

Comment: `setLayoutParams` implies call to `requestLayout()` which is what you needed.